# Converting daily data to fiscal yearly data

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I am trying to train a machine learning model to predict the crop yield of each district of Nepal. The input features will be various weather related data such as temperature, wind speed, etc. and the crop yield is to be predicted based on those data.
For the purpose of training the model, I have found the following data:

- https://github.com/Ashutosh652/csv_files/blob/main/NepalAgriStats_Cereal.csv. This contains the district wise crop yield data of crops of Nepal from the fiscal year 1979/80 to 2013/14. Note that a fiscal year in Nepal starts from July 16 and ends on July 15 of the next year. So, the crop yield in the fiscal year 1979/80 means the crop yield from 16th July 1979 to 15th July 1980.
- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Ashutosh652/csv_files/main/climate_data.csv. This contains the daily climate data of each district of Nepal from 1st January 1981 to 31st December 2019. This data is not in fiscal year but regular year. I could not upload the full dataset to github because it was too large.

What I ultimately want is a dataset that I can use to train a machine learning model with climate data as features and crop yield as outputs. The dataset should contain the columns:

YEAR, DISTRICT, TEMP, MAX_TEMP, MIN_TEMP, ...other climate data..., YIELD.

In this final dataset, I want the climate data and yield for each district for each year.

In order to accomplish this, I need to convert either the crop data from fiscal year to normal year or the climate data from normal year to fiscal year.

I am assuming that it is not possible to convert the crop data from fiscal year to normal year because I only have yearly data of the crop yield and in order to convert this to normal year data, we would need to distinguish the crop yield of a fiscal year into yield before July 16 and yield after July 15. If I am wrong on this, please correct me.

So, the next option is to convert the daily climate data into fiscal yearly data. How can I convert the daily climate data into fiscal yearly data. Note that there are different types of features in the daily climate data that needs to be converted to fiscal yearly data. For instance, there are two features which are average temperature of a day and maximum temperature of a day. To, convert the average temperature of each day into yearly average temperature, we have to find the average of all the daily temperatures. But to convert the daily maximum temperatures into yearly maximum temperature, we have to find the maximum of all the daily maximum temperatures for a year. Again, I could be wrong. Please feel free to correct me.

So, for now, what I want to know is that how can I convert the daily climate data into fiscal yearly climate data?

Also, if you think that this method or dataset is not the best for this kind of project then please inform me of that as well because this is my first time doing a machine learning project on my own.

Also, I most likely would not be using all of the features in the climate dataset for training the machine learning model. But it would still be beneficial to convert all of the climate data if possible so that I can experiment with different features in the later phases of this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compute the min, max and mean of each column for each fiscal year (July 16st to July 15th the next year) and district. *(Then you can choose what columns that you want to use.)*

```py
df = pd.read_csv('climate_data.csv').drop(columns=['LON', 'LAT'])
df.DATE = pd.to_datetime(df.DATE)
df['year'] = df.DATE.dt.year
df.loc[(df.DATE.dt.month > 7) | ((df.DATE.dt.month == 7) & (df.DATE.dt.day > 15)), 'year'] += 1
df.year = df.DATE.dt.year.astype(str) + '/' + (df.DATE.dt.year + 1).astype(str)
df = (
    df.drop(columns='DATE')
    .set_index(['year', 'DISTRICT'])
    .groupby(['year', 'DISTRICT'])
    .agg(['mean', 'min', 'max'])
)
df.columns = ['_'.join(col).strip() for col in df.columns.values]  # flatten multicolumns
```

---

Load the yields data and format it to match the climate data:

```py
df2 = pd.read_csv('NepalAgriStats_Cereal.csv').drop(columns='DISTRICT_CODE').rename(columns={'DISTRICT_NAME': 'year'}).set_index('year').T
df2['product'] = df2.index.map(get_product)
df2['stats_type'] = df2.index.map(get_stats_type)
df2.index = df2.index.map(get_year)
df2 = (
    df2.reset_index()
    .rename(columns={'index': 'year'})
    # get each district, yearm product and stats_type in seperate rows
    .melt(id_vars=['year', 'product', 'stats_type'], var_name='DISTRICT', value_name='yield')
    # pivot to get stats_type as columns
    .pivot_table(index=['year', 'DISTRICT', 'product'], columns='stats_type', values='yield')
    .reset_index('product')
)
df2.columns = df2.columns.values  # flatten multicolumns
```

The code above makes use of the following functions:

```py
def get_product(col):
    return {
        'PD': 'Paddy',
        'WT': 'Wheat',
        'MZ': 'Maize',
        'ML': 'Millet',
        'BL': 'Barley',
        'BW': 'BW'
    }[col.split('_')[0]]


def get_stats_type(col):
    return {
        'P': 'Production',
        'A': 'Area',
        'Y': 'Yield',
    }[col.split('_')[1]]


def get_year(col):
    year = col.split('_')[2][:4]
    return f'{year}/{int(year) + 1}'
```

---

Finally, join the climate data with the yields data:

```py
dataset = df.join(df2, how='inner').set_index('product', append=True)
```

- The final dataset contains, for each ***fiscal year***, ***district***, and *product*, the target variables ***area***, ***production***, and ***yield***, as well as the ***mean***, ***min***, and ***max*** of the ***climate variables***.

---

You might not not want all the ***climate variables***, so just drop the ones that you don't want.

---

You might also only care about ***a specific product***.

E.g. if you are only interested in the ***wheat***, you can remove the other ***products*** this way:

```py
dataset = dataset.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, :, 'Wheat'], :]
```

---

Or you might only care about the ***sum of all products***. If so, add this line prior to joining with the ***climate data***

```py
df2 = df2.groupby(['year', 'DISTRICT']).sum(numeric_only=True)
```

and also remove/comment out the following like this:

```py
dataset = df.join(df2, how='inner')#.set_index('product', append=True)
```

---

- If you are predicting the yield, you will want to separate your dataset so that the training set and the validation/test set do not overlap in time.
- You will also want to normalize your variables.

  - For the your predictor variables *(from the climate data)*, whether this is needed will depend on your choice of model, i.e. for a tree-based model, you might not need to it, but it does not hurt.
  - For your target variables, you will want to normalize them per district, based on the data in your training set. What I mean by this is that, for each district, you compute the average yield on your training set, and divide your target variables on both your training and validation/test set by this/those numbers. Then when you use your model for inference, you multiply for output by the same number. *(This is all generally speaking, and there might be ways of doing things where this is not needed, but this is something that you generally will want to to.)*